# Pathwise differentiability of stochastic integrals

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

**My question:** Is there a necessary and/or sufficient condition we can place on suitable continuous $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which allows us to determine whether the process
$$X_t := \int_0^t f(t-s) dW_s$$
has differentiable paths?

---

I was motivated to ask this after looking at the SDE in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737530/problem-stochastic-differential-equation):
\begin{align}
dX_t &= Y_t dt \\\\
dY_t &= -X_t dt + b dW_t
\end{align}
to which I found the solution, when $X_0 = Y_0 = 0$,
\begin{align}
X_t &= b \int_0^t \sin(t-s) dW_s \\\\
Y_t &= b \int_0^t \cos(t-s) dW_s \\\\
\end{align}
Now, from the SDE and the pathwise continuity of solutions, it is clear to see that $X_t$ will be pathwise differentiable (with derivative $Y_t$), whereas $Y_t$ will not be. However this was unintuitive to me just looking at the integrals themselves!

---

I know from [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953436/partial-derivative-of-ito-integral) that we cannot hope for differentiable paths when we replace the integrand with just $f(s)$. Moreover, I know that convolutions with white noise of the form
\begin{equation}
Y_t := \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-s) dW_s
\end{equation}
are pathwise differentiable if the square of the Fourier transform of $f$ [decays faster than](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://www.uah.edu/images/colleges/science/math/cbms2020/lecture_2_slides.pdf) $|k|^{-1}$ as $|k| \rightarrow \infty$ (the square of the Fourier transform of $f$ is the spectral density of $Y$). However, I don't think this result holds in our case since we aren't integrating over the whole line and, in any case $\sin$ and $\cos$ are not $L^1$.

Comment: Can you show how you found those solutions? I find it hard to believe that one of them is differentiable and the other one is not. This is clear from the system of SDEs but is hard to see in those solutions.

Comment: @KurtG. The general $n$-dimensional SDE with constant coefficients $dX_t = A X_t dt + b dW_t$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is solved by means of the integrating factor $e^{-At}$. That is, $d(e^{-At}X_t) = e^{-At}b dW_t$, and then you can integrate both sides and multiply by $e^{At}$. The reason I asked my question is exactly because it was so unintuitive looking at the form of the solution that one was differentiable and the other one not.

Comment: Sure. We usually solve those systems by writing them matrix-vector form. In your case: 
$$
d\boldsymbol{Z}_t=A\,\boldsymbol{Z}_t\,dt+B\,dW_t\,,\;\boldsymbol{Z}={X\choose Y}\,,\,A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0\\b\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
A bit more details how $X$ ends up with sine and $Y$ with cosine would greatly improve your post I think. I sill find it hard to believe that the $dW$-integral over $\sin(t-s)$ is differentiable in $t\,.$ But I am more than willing to learn something new.

Comment: @KurtG. I am a bit confused as to what you are asking me to clarify. The general SDE I had written in my previous comment is in matrix-vector form. In the case of my original SDE, $$e^{At} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & \sin(t) \\ -\sin(t) & \cos(t) \end{pmatrix},$$ so multiplying $e^{A(t-s)}$ by $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ gives the form of the stochastic integrand for $X$ and $Y$.  You can verify the differentiability of $X_t$ again by using the sine addition formula and Ito's formula to check that the differential has no diffusion term.

Comment: @KurtG. In any case, the main point of my original post was to ask about the conditions required in general for the differentiability of stochastic integrals, and so I didn't want to dwell on the original SDE which was merely presented as motivation.

Comment: Perhaps the way I formatted my question made this unclear, so I have rearranged my exposition to make this more explicit.

Comment: It is a clear and interesting question. The general way you approach it might be quite hard I think. As a fan of examples I found you one more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update***

It is not difficult to show that for $f(t,s)$ that is differentiable in $t$
and nice enough in $s$ to allow for the following integral that
the [stochastic Leibniz rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2677654/949989) holds:
$$
d\Big\{\int_0^tf(t,s)\,dW_s\Big\}=\Big\{\int_0^t\partial_tf(t,s)\,dW_s\Big\}\,dt+f(t,t)\,dW_t\,.
$$
In fact, such manipulations are very common in the mathematical finance literature. What is new in your case is that $f(t,t)=0\,.$ This is untypical in finance but here it trivially leads to the differentiability of $\int_0^tf(t,s)\,dW_s$ in $t\,.$

***Original Answer***

We usually solve those systems by writing them matrix-vector form. In your case:
$$
d\boldsymbol{Z}_t=A\,\boldsymbol{Z}_t\,dt+B\,dW_t\,,\;\boldsymbol{Z}={X\choose Y}\,,\,A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0\\b\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
It is well-known that the matrix exponential of the anti-symmetric matrix
$At$ is a rotation matrix
$$
e^{At}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&\sin t\\-\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Using it as integrating factor, the solution to the SDE is
$$
\boldsymbol{Z}_t=e^{At}\int_0^t e^{-As}B\,dW_s=\int_0^te^{A(t-s)}B\,dW_s=\int_0^tb\begin{pmatrix}\sin(t-s)\\\cos(t-s)\end{pmatrix}\,dW_s\,.
$$
Since $dX_t=Y_t\,dt$ it we know that $X_t$ is differentiable in $t\,.$ This leads to the surprising insight that the stochastic integral
$$
\int_0^t\sin(t-s)\,dW_s
$$
is differentiable in $t\,.$

Let's now consider instead the symmetric matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
It is involutory, $A^2=I$ and [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1819019/949989),
$$
e^{At}=\begin{pmatrix}\cosh t&\sinh t\\\sinh t&\cosh t\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
As above this leads to the insight that the stochastic integral
$$
\int_0^t\sinh(t-s)\,dW_s
$$
is differentiable in $t\,.$

To look for general criteria on $f$ that make the
stochastic integral
$$
\int_0^t f(t-s)\,dW_s
$$
differentiable in $t$ I think studying further matrix exponentials is the
way to go. So far we have seen functions that vanish at zero.

Another popular example is
$$\require{cancel}
\int_0^t(t-s)\,dW_s=tW_t-\int_0^ts\,dW_s=\int_0^tW_s\,ds+\cancel{\int_0^ts\,dW_s}-\cancel{\int_0^ts\,dW_s}
$$
which is directly seen to be differentiable.

Comment: I think I've found a Fourier analysis-type argument to show that continuous functions $f$ with $f(0)=0$ will work.

Comment: @Julius Very curious to see that.

Comment: Have a look and see if you think it checks out.

Comment: @Julius After realising how simple it is I am sure your proof also checks out but there are better experts than me who will know how much further the assumptions on $f$ can be weakened.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formal Fourier analysis-type argument to show that, for those $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = 0$ ,
$$X_t = X_t(f) = \int_0^t f(t-s) dW_s$$
will have differentiable paths. Observe that this is all $f$ which have a continuous odd extension to $\mathbb{R}$.

If we assume for now that $f$ has a Fourier transform representation of the form
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ipt} \hat{f}(p) dp$$
where $\hat{f}$ is real, then we can plug this into our expression for $X$ and (assuming we can swap integrals with some stochastic variant of Fubini's theorem), we can consider
$$Y_t(p) := \int_0^t e^{ip(t-s)} dW_s.$$
The Ito differential for this is
$$dY_t(p) = \left ( -p \int_0^t \sin(p(t-s))\, dW_s \, dt + dW_t \right ) + ip \int_0^t \cos(p(t-s))\, dW_s \, dt$$
and so in particular the imaginary part of $Y_t(p)$ is diffuion-free, for any $p$. Hence we argue that, for
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(pt) \hat{f}(p) dp,$$
$X_t(f)$ will have differentiable paths. After a bit of rearranging, we deduce that this is equivalent to requiring $f$ to have an odd, pure-imaginary Fourier transform $\hat{f}$. And so [$f$ itself is  odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184332/fourier-transform-of-even-odd-function), as a function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Now all of this assumes that $f$ is $L^1$, so it has a Fourier transform, and this transform is invertible. However, for general odd $f$, and for any $T > 0$ we can consider a continuous odd function $g \in L^1$ which is equal to $f$ on $[-T,T]$ and decays sufficiently fast to 0 outside this interval, so that $g$ is also invertible. Then we will have $(X_t(g))_{0 \leq t < T} \overset{d}{=} (X_t(f))_{0 \leq t < T}$ as processes, and hence conclude that $X_t(f)$ will also have differentiable paths.

I am a bit unsure as to where the assumption of continuity is required, although clearly it is required, since the function $h$ with $h(0)=0$, $h(x) = 1$ for all $x > 0$ has $X_t(h) = W_t$, and so doesn't have differentiable paths.